# Date prompt in BO

Tags: business-objects

I have a webi report that accepts a date input.
I need to receive data from the user in the format "dd-Mmm-YYYY"; however the calendar control that BO presents to the user for date selection is always shown in M/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM.

Is there any way to control this behaviour?

Comment: what calendar control are you using?

Comment: ? Somthing that comes embedded in Infoview.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing all the date fields in the Universe designer to the format that you want? You can either format them using SQL in the select statement box of the "Object Properties", or you can change the format of the field by right clicking and selecting "Object Format..."

I'm pretty sure that would affect the way the end user sees it.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the date format  (and all other format ) on  the locatizion parametrs on the user setting for each user you have in cms , simply by the infoview preferences for each user .

home screen of central management  -> preferences  - > Preferred Viewing Locale + local time zone.
or
home screen of infoview -> preferences  - > Preferred Viewing Locale + local time zone.

this will set also the date prompt format

Answer (score 0):

There's another option.

On the BO server there's a javascript file that is used to create the calendar popup.

```
..\Tomcat55\webapps\AnalyticalReporting\viewers\cdz_adv\lib\calendar.js
```

Inside this file there's a function called `CTFB_setFormatInfo` which if passed a date format uses it ... if not there's seems to be a hard coded default of "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a".

I'm pretty certain this is not updated by the other dozen ways to set the date format found in BO (user prefs, prn file, object properties ect).

```
function CTFB_setFormatInfo(format,arrDays,arrMonth,AM,PM)
{
var o=this
o.arrMonthNames=arrMonth?arrMonth:_month
o.arrDayNames=arrDays?arrDays:_day
o.format=format?format:"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
o.AM=AM?AM:_AM
o.PM=PM?PM:_PM
}
```

I just updated this file - and now I get consistent dd/mm/yyyy - without pesky mm/dd/yyyy randomly turning up when the preference isn't passed through.